# How to set combobox value to null or empty while loading data to it from database in c#.net

Tags: c#, combobox

I have a windows form coded in c#..
the problem is I have a combobox which is loaded values from database,and that code has written in LOAD form..

so,my form's combobox values are generated automatically to it and the Initial combobx text is loaded to it..

I want to set combobox initial text or value should be empty or null..
please help me to solve it..
Thanx in advance
my code is as follows

```
 try
       {
           ConnectionStringSettings consettings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["attendancemanagement"];
           string connectionString = consettings.ConnectionString;
           SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
           cn.Open();
           SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select employee_id,employee_name,image from Employee_Details", cn);
           SqlDataReader dtr;
           dtr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
           DataTable dt = new DataTable();
           dt.Columns.Add("employee_id", typeof(string));
           dt.Columns.Add("employee_name", typeof(string));
           dt.Load(dtr);
           //Convert.ToString.comboBox1.Items.Insert("", 0);
           comboBox1.DisplayMember = "employee_id";
           comboBox1.DisplayMember = "employee_name";
           comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
           //dateTimePicker1.Enabled = true; ;
           cn.Close();
       }

       catch (Exception e1)
       {
           MessageBox.Show(e1.Message);

       }
```

Comment: try my answer hope it will work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this line after you set your datasource to `db`:

```
comboBox1.SelectedItem = null;
```

Or

```
comboBox1.SelectedItem = -1;
```

Comment: hi..cannot set the value to be null eror is generating after copied ur caode..@alex

Comment: Oh! that's what I do using `Telerik ComboBoxes`. Didn't noticed it doesn't work on the original ones. I'll check for a Microsoft solution

Answer (score 0):

do not make it null, better to writer it **Select** as selected value.

```
           `dt.Load(dtr);
            DataRow drow = dt.NewRow();
            drow[0] = "-1";
            drow[1] = "Select";
            drow[2] = string.Empty;
            dt.Rows.InsertAt(drow, 0);
            dt.AcceptChanges();
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "employee_id";
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "employee_name";
            comboBox1.DataSource = dt;`
```